# jQuery css() not updating width

Tags: jquery

This doesn't do anything:

```
$('#searchprogress .progress-bar').css("width","0%");
```

But interestingly, this works fine:

```
$('#searchprogress .progress-bar').animate({
    width: "0%"
  }, 10);
```

Why? (and thanks)

Comment: wrap your code line in document.ready event

Comment: Try `width: "0"` instead of `width: "0%"`

Comment: By default, jQuery adds a `px` unit to the values passed to the `.css()` method. This behavior can be prevented by adding the property to the `jQuery.cssNumber` object : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/

Comment: A width of `0%` is invalid. Animate does not just set css property. It calculates the new css property. So using `+=20px` jQuery adds 20px to the current state. So will `0%` be animated to `0` or `0px`.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/avsrS/

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to use a unit of measurement when your value is "0" - you can save yourself a few bytes here and there :)

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes and with the same code working fine by my side,

Please be sure of the jQuery version you are using, older versions might have some problem..

I have updated [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/NfKFq/1/) please refer the fiddle for working code

Note: I am using jQuery 1.9.1

and to debug with click I have added button with this code,

```
$("#btn").click(
    function(){$('#searchprogress #progressbar').css("width","0%");});
```

this works fine in this fiddle, you must have missed something small, please re-verify the names with html source.. that can be the only reason..